# laravel sail for older laravel versions

Tags: php, laravel, docker

https://laravel.build/my-app
gives bash script to create sail container for latest laravel 8 version.

I took this script and tried to customize it for 7.* version, all same except this:

```
docker run --rm
-v $(pwd):/opt
-w /opt
laravelsail/php80-composer:latest
bash -c "composer create-project laravel/laravel my-app \"7.*\" && cd my-app &&     php ./artisan sail:install --with=mysql"
```

It completes but then
/my-app$ ls ./vendor/bin/sail
ls: cannot access './vendor/bin/sail': No such file or directory
sail fails to install.

I tried to use laravelsail/php74-composer image from
https://hub.docker.com/search?q=laravelsail&type=image
yet it didn't succeed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience sail doesn't work well if your on windows.

I've always had to run it through an ubuntu VM/ mac and it works fine. There possibly are some work arounds, I just think it wasn't tested for windows

Comment: Thank's for your answer.
In my case, with latest Windows home WSL2 it worked fine for laravel 8.
It's not windows in this case.

Answer (score 0):

After trying again error messages point that sail's dependencies are not get satisfied by laravel 7 version.
More reading clarifies, that unfortunately current sail is supposed to work with Laravel 8 only.